# SQL Query with WHERE NOT does not filter corretly

Tags: sql, where-clause

I am using a WHERE statement to filter tracks by certain criteria, mainly by some specific ID, track distance and track longitude/latitude values. The problematic part starts with the first "AND NOT".
Here is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT mobtrack.track.id AS track_id, mobtrack.track.user_id AS vehicle_id 
FROM mobtrack.track 
INNER JOIN sensor.location 
ON mobtrack.track.user_id = sensor.location.vehicle_id 
WHERE mobtrack.track.user_id = 1343904522 
AND mobtrack.track.distance >= 20 
AND mobtrack.track.distance <= 25 
AND NOT sensor.location.longitude <= 11.50 
AND NOT sensor.location.longitude >= 11.72 
AND NOT sensor.location.latitude <= 48.14 
AND NOT sensor.location.latitude >= 48.34 
LIMIT 100
```

I am trying to apply the following conditions (sorted in the right order as in the query):

1. Query only tracks with a certain user_id
2. Query only tracks between 20-25km
3. DO NOT query any track with latitude values lower than 48.14, higher than 48.34 and longitude values lower than 11.50, higher than 11.72. I am trying to achieve this by saying "do not query any track with latitude/longitude values above or below the limit. If I query it the other way around (only tracks with lat/long values within those boundaries), I get tracks which have values inside the boundaries but also outside the boundaries. **I only need those tracks with explicitly no values outside the boundaries**.

The query, as it is now, works, but outputs tracks with longitude/latitude information outside the wanted boundaries. How can I use a WHERE NOT or AND NOT statement to achieve this?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and the results you are getting (perhaps in a SQL/DB fiddle of some sort)?  Also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: What if you reverse the condition ? `AND sensor.location.longitude > 11.50 `

Answer (score 0):

I would phrase this as:
Your query *should* work, assuming that you only care about 1 location.  I would, however, phrase it using `BETWEEN` and using table aliases:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.id AS track_id, t.user_id AS vehicle_id 
FROM mobtrack.track t JOIN
     sensor.location l
     ON t.user_id = l.vehicle_id 
WHERE t.user_id = 1343904522 AND
      t.distance >= 20 AND
      t.distance <= 25 AND
      l.longitude BETWEEN 11.50 AND 11.72 AND
      l.latitude BETWEEN 48.14 AND 48.34 ;
```

That said, I suspect that you might have multiple locations per track and want *no* rows that are outside the boundaries.  If so, you would want aggregation or `NOT EXISTS`.  The latter is perhaps better:

```
SELECT t.id AS track_id, t.user_id AS vehicle_id 
FROM mobtrack.track t  
WHERE t.user_id = 1343904522 AND
      t.distance >= 20 AND
      t.distance <= 25 AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM sensor.location l
                  WHERE t.user_id = l.vehicle_id AND
                        NOT (l.longitude BETWEEN 11.50 AND 11.72 AND
                             l.latitude BETWEEN 48.14 AND 48.34
                            )
                  );
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response. My knowledge would not have allowed me to write the second query you suggested. But from reading it, it seems as if it is exactly what I need: Because no latitude/longitude values in a track can be outside the boundaries. 
As you say: I have multiple locations per track and I want to exclude any track who's lat/long values are outside the boundaries. 
I tried your second query and it still has not finished (30min after starting it). 
Sadly I can not provide any sample data because I am not allowed to. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: @User5644 . . . You can *make up* sample data that looks reasonable.  The data doesn't have to be real, only representative.